# How to add resource_picker in any engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I guess I need to formulate the question better!

I want to add two new Resource fields in the refinerycms-calendar
engine, in the admin area.

The fields will actually be video files, the first for the video of
the party and the second for the interview of the contributors. I have
done the following:

1. Added to 01_create_events.rb migration:

   ```
   t.integer :video_live_id
   t.integer :video_interview_id
   ```
2. Added to the Event.rb model:

   ```
   belongs_to :video_live, :class_name=>'Resource'
   belongs_to :video_interview,:class_name=>'Resource'
   ```
3. Added this to the _form.html.erb view in Admin:

   ```
   <div class='field'>
       <%= f.label :video_live -%>
      <%= render :partial => "/shared/admin/resource_picker", :locals =>
   {
             :f => f,
             :field => :video_live_id,
            :resource => @event.video_live

            } %>
     </div>

   <div class='field'>
       <%= f.label :video_interview -%>
       <%= render :partial => "/shared/admin/resource_picker", :locals =>
   {
             :f => f,
             :field => :video_interview_id,
             :resource => @event.video_interview} %>
     </div>
   ```

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `video_live_id' for #<Event:0x1049b9f88>
```

What am I not doing well?

Thanks,

Petros

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how refinery implements its resources, but it uses [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/) to manage file attachments (i.e. resources). I'm currently modifying an old refinery setup (version 1)   and since documentation was impossible to find, I just followed the dragonfly usage instructions - which seems to work fine.